# Why an internal map, maps an internal set to an internal set?

Tags: logic, model-theory, nonstandard-models

In this [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eroquette/1975-RobinsonRoquette.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi7naKOm6nuAhWLy4UKHRo5CwQQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw17qUOrEFjVbNQMMMLJZcb9) page 129, assumed as a fact that an internal map, maps internal subsets to internal subsets but I can't see why this happens.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function $f$ in $M$ trivially has the property that the image of every set under $f$ is a set. We can express the property in the formal language of $M$ (since said language is higher-order, consult page 125, paragraph 3), as e.g. $\forall S. \exists S'. \forall x. x \in S' \leftrightarrow \exists y \in S. f(y) = x$.

By the Extension Principle (Section 2.2. of page 126), every property of $f$ which is expressible in the language of $M$ also holds for its extension in $\!^{\star}M$, with the caveat that the quantifiers now range over internal entities (page 125, bullet point iii). So we obtain the property that the image of every internal set under the *standard* function $f$ is itself an internal set.

A similar argument (using an additional $\forall f$ and appealing to the permanence principle instead of extension) allows us to conclude that generally the image of every internal set under an *internal* function is itself internal.